# How redirect to homepage with php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need do a automatic foward/redirect.

If the user dont click anywhere in the site five seconds after automatic foward to homepage... it is possible?

For example,

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="5;URL=http://www.teste.com/sv1/index.html">
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to learn where PHP starts and stops in the page request pricess

Comment: In what respect does your example fail to do what you want?

Comment: [take a look at this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253223/redirect-in-php?rq=1)... I think it might be the same question.  I would personally use jquery for this, though, [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276677/jquery-redirect-to-url-after-specified-time) or [this with an "abort" option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234017/jquery-redirect-on-click-or-after-10-seconds/3234034#3234034)

Comment: PHP is an server side scripting language it can not do what you desire here.

Answer (score 3):

try this in your head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var redirect = setTimeout(function() {
    window.location = "http://stackoverflow.com";
}, 5000);

document.onclick = function() {
    clearTimeout(redirect);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, almost there... works but just click once to not return to work... it only works when we open the page and do nothing, if i click anywhere e never works again

Comment: So you want the 5 second timer to restart after each click?

Comment: Yes... ever click restart the time

Comment: Why do you want that behavior?

Comment: To use in multimedia kiosk

Comment: Yes, but why would a user click to delay a redirect?

Answer (score 0):

In PHP it's not possible. You can add timeout in JS and stop it when user click somewhere (onclick event on body).

After that timeout (without clicks), yuo can redirect user by setting `document.location.href` to your homepage.

Answer (score 0):

**Short:** No.

**Longer:** This is not possible with PHP, because PHP is precompiled on the server. So as soon as the user sees the page on his browser, the PHP script already ran through. You will have to use something else instead, for example JavaScript.

Comment: Can do in other language?

Comment: There are several ways to implement a redirection (meta command as you used above, .htaccess, PHP etc.). But if you want to count the seconds you won't be able to avoid JavaScript.